# Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool Unable to Connect BUT Can connect to Dedicated SQL Pool?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

My team is currently test driving Azure Synapse and we are hitting some role permissions that confused us a bit.

I was given the role of "Synapse Contributor" initially so I am able to log into the workspace and look around.

BUT when I try to use the built in serverless SQL pool I hit the following error:

`You don't have access to the serverless SQL pool, Built-in. To be granted access, contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.`

Weird thing is that for a newly created dedicated SQL pool I have no problem accessing it.

Now my admin played around and gave me "Synapse SQL Adminstrator" THEN I was able to access both the serverless and dedicated SQL pools.

So Im a bit concerned as I dont want to be giving out an administrator role to every person that wants to use the serverless SQL pool.

Questions

-Is this "expected"? That anyone needing access to the serverless SQL pool needs to be given this admin role? Or is there some other role or setting we are missing?

-Secondly - How come I am able to access the dedicated SQL pool as a regular Synapse contributor BUT not able to access the serverless SQL pool?

Comment: You can also `CREATE USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` to create AAD users without giving them any specific roles and then grant permissions to those. I've done that to allow managed service identities to connect to the serverless end point and run stored procs

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thats actually my second question! From what I read in the docs, we can use the `CREATE USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` and from here someone could use for example SSMS and connect using a user ID and password. **Question:** Can this same user with the SQL user ID & password use these to then also connect to the Azure Synapse Workspace & the Serverless SQL pool if we give them the "Synapse Contributor" role? I was really curious if this is possible - We dont want to be giving out "Synapse Admin" to every one that wants to login to the serverless pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this "expected"? That anyone needing access to the serverless SQL pool needs to be given this admin role? Or is there some other role or setting we are missing?

As mentioned in [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles#built-in-synapse-rbac-roles-and-scopes) to access Serverless SQL you need either Synapse Administrator or Synapse SQL Administrator role.

See [Grant Access to SQL pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control#step-7-grant-access-to-sql-pools) for examples of SQL scripts for granting SQL permissions in SQL pools.

> How come I am able to access the dedicated SQL pool as a regular Synapse contributor BUT not able to access the serverless SQL pool?

To access Serverless SQL you need either Synapse Administrator or Synapse SQL Administrator role.

To access Dedicated SQL you need either Synapse Administrator or Synapse Contributor role.

See [Synapse Roles and Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles#built-in-synapse-rbac-roles-and-scopes) for more understanding of Synapse Built-in Roles.

Comment: -When granting "SQL Permissions" to a serverless SQL pool - Does this mean that a user would get a user ID/password and then be able to login via for example SSMS? Or can this user also access the serverless SQL pool through the Synapse workspace? Basically what would be the minimum set up needed to grant someone access to the Synapse workspace + serverless SQL pool through the workspace? Can we grant for example Synapse Contributor and then SQL permissions? Or is SQL permissions ONLY for access OUTSIDE the Synapse workspace? Im confused on the difference between SQL permissions vs workspace